# How to include the meta keyword and meta description in the page?

Tags: keyword, meta

I have the following code:

```
<%@ Page Title="Spam Filter, Free Exchange Spam Filter – Software to Stop Spam" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBreadCrumb" Runat="Server">
    Welcome to > <a href="Default.aspx">Home</a>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentBodyMain" Runat="Server">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`<asp:HtmlMeta>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlmeta%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control. On the .aspx file you write:

```
<asp:HtmlMeta ID="descriptionMeta" runat="server" />
<asp:HtmlMeta ID="keywordMeta" runat="server" />
```

Then, from the code, you can do this to set content etc.

```
this.descriptionMeta.Name = "description";
this.descriptionMeta.Content = "description of the page or whatever";
this.keywordMeta.Name = "keywords";
this.keywordMeta.Content = "some,keywords,and,things";
```